# increasing the size of the coloured squares on histogram legends in R

Tags: r

I am trying to increase the size of the coloured squares in the legend on a histogram in R - when I output the PDFs they are too small so it is hard to distinguish the colours. I've searched Google, the R-help Nabble forum and this place, all to no avail. I've also tried several of the commands in the legend documentation.

What do I need to use in the legend() function to increase them? and is it possible to remove the black border around each coloured square to ease viewing?

Here my example:

```
a<-c(1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,54,56,2,23,1,3,23)
hist(a) 
graphics::legend(x=-1,y=10,c(">0%",">20%",">40%",">60%",">80%"),
       x.intersp=1,y.intersp=2,cex=1, bty="n",
       fill=c("black","gray50","gray70","gray85","white"))
```

[image]

I wish to change the size of box in the legend?

---

SOLUTION: from @Ben Bolker

add to the script above the legend function

```
> source("http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/legendx.R")
```

then add

```
> box.cex=c(2,2)
```

within the legend function

Comment: can you post what did you try please? I mean your R code

Comment: W/o seeing your code, it's hard to help.  Most likely adding the `cex` or `pt.cex` argument will do what you want, but it depends on how you're creating the squares.

Comment: legend(x=-1,y=1800,c(">0%",">20%",">40%",">60%",">80%"), x.intersp=1,y.intersp=2,cex=cex, bty="n", fill=c("black","gray50","gray70","gray85","white"))

Comment: cex is set to 0.6, increasing that changes the text and the square, I would like to change them independently

Comment: you can see it on a histogram here a<-c(1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,54,56,2,23,1,3,23)
hist(a)
legend(x=-1,y=10,c(">0%",">20%",">40%",">60%",">80%"), x.intersp=1,y.intersp=2,cex=cex, bty="n", fill=c("black","gray50","gray70","gray85","white"))

Comment: it would help to edit your question to add the example code rather than leaving it languishing in the comments.

Comment: I modified Ben's version of the `legend` function to take a `cex.lab` argument as well.  Just use `source("http://www.pauljhurtado.com/R/code/legendxx.R")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hacked the source of the `legend` function to allow a `box.cex` argument that specifies the relative x and y dimensions of the box.  This isn't perfect -- if the expansion is big enough then you have to adjust `y.intersp` to prevent the fill boxes from overlapping.

```
source("http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/legendx.R")
a<-c(1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,54,56,2,23,1,3,23)
cex <- 1
hist(a)
legend("topright",c(">0%",">20%",">40%",">60%",">80%"),
       bty="n",
       fill=c("black","gray50","gray70","gray85","white"),
       box.cex=c(3,3),
       y.intersp=2.8)
```

[image]

Comment: great !  does this work with diffrent shapes , something like  pch=c(24,22,21,23,25)? can't test I have a bug with your code 'can't find rep_len'

Comment: @agstudy, I think if you're using points then your answer (`pt.cex`) is correct ...

Comment: `rep_len` may have appeared in a fairly recent version of R (I'm using development R); I think you can define it as `rep_len <- function(x, length.out) rep(x,length.out)`.  I will update the file on the web accordingly.

Comment: if I get around to it I may see if I can get some variant of this included in base R ...

Comment: definitely would be useful to add in to the basic legend function options

Comment: FWIW, I further hacked Ben's version of the `legend` function to also take a `cex.lab` argument.  It can be sourced via `source("http://www.pauljhurtado.com/R/code/legendxx.R")`

Answer (score 7):

You can use very thick lines, with rectangular ends.

```
plot( 1, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "" ) # Empty plot
par( lend = 1 ) # Rectangular line endings
legend(
  "topleft",
  c( "Red", "Black" ),
  col = c("red", "black"),
  lty = 1, lwd = 10
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to mix the option **fill** and change the size of the box.

But we can have something with options  **pt.cex** and **pch** without **fill** options.

```
a<-c(1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,54,56,2,23,1,3,23)
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
hist(a) 

graphics::legend(x=10,y=10,c(">0%",">20%",">40%",">60%",">80%"), 
                 x.intersp=1,y.intersp=1,cex=c(1),bty="n",
                 fill=c("black","gray50","gray70","gray85","white"),
             #    pch=c(24,22,21,23,25),
                 pt.cex = c(2,2,2,2,5), 
                 lwd=1.5,title='Histo fill option') 

hist(a) 

graphics::legend(x=10,y=10,c(">0%",">20%",">40%",">60%",">80%"), 
       x.intersp=1,y.intersp=1,cex=c(1),bty="n",
       pch=c(24,22,21,23,25),
       pt.cex = c(1,2,3,3,4), 
       lwd=1.5, title = 'Histo whithout fill ')
```

[image]

Comment: That has changed the size of the text, I would like to keep the text size I have whilst increasing the squares size

Comment: you just play with pt.cex and keep cex the same , you will modify the size of squares and keep the text the same

Comment: that doesn't do anything to mine. this is how mine looks (on an irrelevant purely example histogram) >>>


a<-c(1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,54,56,2,23,1,3,23) hist(a) legend(x=-1,y=10,c(">0%",">20%",">40%",">60%",">80%"), x.intersp=1,y.intersp=2,cex=cex, bty="n", fill=c("black","gray50","gray70","gray85","white"))

Comment: Both agstudy and I have told you to try `pt.cex`  Please do so before commenting that it doesn't help.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I think it really doesn't.  I think the OP wants filled boxes.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think he has problem because he try he uses option fill.