# In R, how to combine an expression with a string on two lines in legend labels?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot on the same figure the results returned by two methods, m1 and m2. In my particular case, the label of the first method is an expression (because it has a subscript) and the label of the second method is on two lines (because it is long). However, having these two requirements doesn't work:

```
l <- list("m1"=list(data=1:10, col=2, label=expression(paste("method 1 (", X[a], ")"))))
l[["m2"]] <- list(data=rep(3,10), col=3, label="method 2 (with a\nlong explanation)")
plot(l[["m1"]]$data, col=l[["m1"]]$col); points(l[["m2"]]$data, col=l[["m2"]]$col)
legend("topleft", legend=c(l[["m1"]]$label, l[["m2"]]$label), col=c(l[["m1"]]$col, l[["m2"]]$col), pch=1)
```

As you can see in the legend, the 2nd label (the one on two lines) overlaps with the first label.

The problem disappears when I don't use an expression for the first label:

```
legend("topleft", legend=c("method 1 (Xa)", l[["m2"]]$label), col=c(l[["m1"]]$col, l[["m2"]]$col), pch=1)
```

The problem also disappears when the second label is on a single line:

```
legend("topleft", legend=c(l[["m1"]]$label, "method 2 (with a long explanation)"), col=c(l[["m1"]]$col, l[["m2"]]$col), pch=1)
```

However, I really need both the expression and the two lines. Any idea?

ps: I'm using R 2.14.1 on Lubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with **y.intersep** and **cex**  parameters.

```
legend("topleft", 
       legend=c(l[["m1"]]$label, 
                l[["m2"]]$label),
       col=c(l[["m1"]]$col,l[["m2"]]$col), 
       pch=0.5,title.adj=100,cex=0.8,y.intersp=2
       )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it's kind of a hack ;) I was hoping for a solution which properly places the symbol (pch=1) in the middle of the 2 lines. I tried to play with "adj" also, but it doesn't do it well. I guess I'll have to make the legend entirely by hand.

Comment: @wfoolhill We can't do it! But it is easy to hack legend code. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644149/increasing-the-size-of-the-coloured-squares-on-histogram-legends-in-r should help you